# Calculate logical pixels from millimeters

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a design with widths, heights, paddings... in millimeters. I'm now trying to figure out how to convert those numbers to the logical pixel system Flutter uses.
I found [the docs for the device pixel ratio](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html) but I'm not sure how to interpret that number and I quote:

> The Flutter framework operates in logical pixels, so it is rarely necessary to directly deal with this property.

So I am not sure if this is the way to go.
My question comes down to this: Is there an easy way to calculate from millimeter to logical pixels that works for both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flutter's unit is DP or dip (aka density independent pixels).
Like it's name is implying, it's independent from the screen pixel ratio.

What's the difference with millimeters ? None really important. 
Converting mm>dp or dp>mm is similar to mm>inch/inch>mm.

The relationship between them is fairly simple :

1 inch = 25.4 mm = 160.0 DP

Which means 1 mm = 6.299 DP

Comment: Hey, where did you get this from? It doesn't seem to be true in practice, for any Android phone I tested.

Comment: https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/

`The MyAppBar widget creates a Container with a height of 56 device-independent pixels `

Comment: I went there, but that says nothing about the number of mm or inches.

Comment: `device-independent pixel` is an offical unit called `dp` or `dip` which has the equivalence I listed above. There's no need for them to explain it. The unit, by definition, is related to inches/mm

Comment: By definition?, where is the definition? Can you please show the link.

Comment: Ok, I found it here as well: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskUseDP

Comment: In any case, unfortunately is not true in practice.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the current accepted answer is not really accurate.

You can print the number of logical pixels for real phones, like this:

```
maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; 
maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; 
print("maxWidth = $maxWidth / maxHeight = $maxHeight");
```

I would appreciate if someone with real iPhones and iPads could run this code and tell me the resulting maxWidth and maxHeights. So far, with Android phones, I've compiled the results comparing with the real phone sizes. What I got is this:

- Galaxy S6 ➜ 5.668537826 dp/mm for height, and 5.668537826 dp/mm for width.
- Galaxy S7 ➜ 5.668537826 dp/mm for height, and 5.668537826 dp/mm for width.
- Galaxy S9 ➜ 5.223614747 dp/mm for height, and 5.585946405 dp/mm for width.
- Pixel XL ➜ 5.612956709 dp/mm for height, and 6.007177748 dp/mm for width.

*See my spreadsheet here:* https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zmGyeKSf4w4B-bX4HSY4oSuh9RkIIkFwYSd3P9C7eX8/edit?usp=sharing

**Update:**

- Android docs (https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskUseDP) say "One dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density)". That's obviously not true in practice for Samsung and Google phones. Or it is, if you pay attention to the word "roughly".
- Flutter docs (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html) say it's 3.8 logical pixels per mm, which is obviously very false.

Comment: Then submit a bug. Because it is supposed to be fixed. Maybe the pixelratio fetched by Flutter is incorrect, leading to invalid numbers.

Comment: So far, the only place in the docs I found a reference to this is here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html. It says there are roughly 3.8 logical pixels per millimeter. Which is obviously VERY wrong in practice.

Comment: Also found it here: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskUseDP which says: "One dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density)."

Comment: The unit is constant. It's not like pixels. There's no such "Samsung/Google phones have a different dip". That's not possible.

Comment: Remi, the Wikipedia article you linked says it is 160 dpi, but the SOURCE of the Wikipedia article you linked says it is "roughly" 160 dpi. So the unit is not constant, and the Wikipedia article is wrong.  And the reality is that logical pixels are different for each phone, when measured. The reality determines what is possible, not Wikipedia.

Comment: 160 DP is equal to 1 inch. That's the specs of the unit. It never ever change. That's the whole purpose of using that unit.

Comment: DP to px/inch/mm converter based on pixel density : http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/

Answer (score 0):

Logical pixel is the ratio of dots per unit distance(mm), so you have to change your question to *How many dots per mm represents 1 logical pixel?*

As it is mentioned [here](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/)

> Flutter follows a simple density-based format like iOS. Assets might
>   be 1.0x, 2.0x, 3.0x, or any other multiplier. Flutter doesn’t have dps
>   but there are logical pixels, which are basically the same as
>   device-independent pixels. The so-called devicePixelRatio expresses
>   the ratio of physical pixels in a single logical pixel.

And as mentioned `1.0x` logical pixel ratio represents `mdpi` in Android density qualifiers. And according to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities), `mdpi ≃ 160DPI` and as `dpi` represents the number of individual dots that can be placed in a line within the span of 1 inch (2.54 cm) so:

```
160dpi = 160 dots per inch = 6.299 dots per mm
```

And as `mdpi ≃ 160DPI`  and 1 logical pixel represents `mdpi` so:

```
1.0x logical pixel ratio ≃ 6.299 dots per mm
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a widget at a real size.

```dart
double millimeterToSize(double millimeter) => millimeter * 160 * 0.03937;
```